# C# JSON Get specific attribute with multiple roots

Tags: c#, json, json.net, screen-scraping

So basically, I am building a C# application that will retrieve specific values from a URL. The URL is
[URL to Scrape](http://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/uk_UK/Product-GetVariants?pid=BY1910)

The attributes that I need to grab are: 'id', 'size', 'inStock' and 'ATS' from each different size of product.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9CSo.png)

I have tried the code from [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38421858/get-json-specific-attribute-value-c-sharp) but no luck.

```
string data = client.DownloadString(region).Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace(@"\", "").Replace("\t", "");
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
var someVar1 = dynObj["variants"]["BY1910_530"][1]["id"].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(someVar1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like this (As you are using JsonConvert, I assume you've already got the Newtonsoft.Json Nuget package):

```
var client = new HttpClient();
string json = await client.GetStringAsync(@"http://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/uk_UK/Product-GetVariants?pid=BY191");
var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine(jobj["variations"]["variants"][1]["id"].ToString());
```